# drop down list load data from database php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

The loaded data doesn't show in the drop down list

please give me a solution

```
<html>
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pestpack");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
mysqli_select_db($con,"pestpack");

$query1 = "SELECT teamname FROM team";
if($rs1 = mysqli_query($con,$query1))
?>
<select>
<option>select a team</option>
<?php
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($rs1))
{
  echo '<option value="'.$row['teamname'].'">' . $row['teamname'] . '</option>';      
}
?>
</select>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, we are going to need a LOT more information than that and a code extract

Comment: echo '<option value=\"{$row['teamname']}\">{$row['teamname']}</option>'; it doesn't work anjith

Comment: we need more info: is the script connecting to database? is there something in the database? does mysqli_fetch_array return something? Also for future reference, do NOT write html, php and sql in the same file!

Comment: What kind of error/result you are getting? You should have getting some errors here I think.

Comment: Can you show of `print_r($rs1)`?

Comment: Okay friends ..i am first time here  there ia a table TEAM (teanno,Teamname) i database..i have enterd some rows there.i try to select those teamname from TEAM table and display those teamname(ie column in TEAM table) in drop downlist. my error is I CAN'T SEE TEAMNAME IN DROPDOWN LIST.

Answer (score 1):

Populate like this,

```
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pestpack");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }
        // mysqli_select_db($con,"pestpack"); No need to select it again, already mentioned in connection

        $query1 = "SELECT teamname FROM team";
        $rs1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($con,$query1);

        echo '<select>';
        echo '<option>select a team</option>';

        foreach($rs1 as $row) {    
          echo '<option value="'.$row['teamname'].'">' . $row['teamname'] . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
```

This for insert a data in another table.

```
<form method="POST" action="team_insert.php"> <!-- Also define it using `echo` -->
    <!-- This is generated html select tag-->
    <select name="team">  <!-- Define name attribute -->
       <option value="team1">team1</option>
       <option value="team2">team2</option>
       <option value="team3">team3</option>
       <option value="team4">team4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Insert" />
</form>
```

Now in `team_insert.php` write your insert logic

```
  if((isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) && 
     ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $_POST['team']) {
     $selected_team = $_POST['team'];
     // $selected_team variable grap your dropdown value.
     // Then write a query logic to insert
  }
```

Comment: good it works..now it is php file .how can i store selected teamname in another table in the database

Comment: If it works accept the answer. I can't get it what you are trying to say?

Comment: yes it works..but i want to store the selected data in another table how can i do it..i accept your comment

Comment: For that, you can create a form around the `SELECT` tag. Use any of `POST` or `GET` method to get the selected value. I updated my answer.

Comment: hi, you have given team1,team2,team3,team4 explicitly in Option tag.But for me,i want to load that teamnames from a table and display in the option tag.we done that already.but when  we select a teamname from option tag,i need to insert the selected teamname in another table in the database.i want to load teamanems from database to option tag and upload selected teamname to another table in database at the same time.i think you got my idea

Comment: I got it. That's the way I coded. See your need to insert the selected team from the `team` dropdown right?. So you must want a button to `INSERT` the data with form tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
           <html>
            <?php

            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pestpack");

            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
              {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
              }
            mysqli_select_db($con,"pestpack");

            $query1 = "SELECT teamname FROM team";
            $rs1 = mysql_fetch_array($con,$query1);
            ?>

            <select>
            <option>select a team</option>
            <?php

            foreach ($rs1 as $row) {    
              echo '<option value=\"{$row['teamname']}\">{$row['teamname']}</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help some one!!!**

```
  $conn = mysql_connect("","","");
                            mysql_select_db("databaseName",$conn);
                    $sc = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Client_table.Name, Client_table.Client_Id 
                            FROM Client_table, user 
                            WHERE user.username = '$sc' 
                            AND Client_table.Branch = user.area 
                            Order by Name ASC");
                    //$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($conn, $query1);

                    echo '<select class="element select large" id="element_17" name="element_17">';
                    echo '<option> Select Company Name</option>';

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['Name'].'">' . $row['Name']. '</option>';                   
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
```